# How to use session object in title option in bootstrap tour?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tour in my application.I want to display the logon user name in 'title' in bootstrap tour steps.I have username stored in session object.How can I use the session object in title?

Js code:

```
// Instance the tour
var tour = new Tour({
  steps: [
  {
    element: "#my-element",
    title: "Welcome to the tour" +'@Session["User"]',
    content: "Content of my step"
  },
  {
    element: "#my-other-element",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  }
]});

// Initialize the tour
tour.init();

// Start the tour
tour.start();
```

Comment: Which backend coding you are using??

Comment: i am using Asp.net Mvc5.i m storing session object value in controller and i have written above js in razor view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is when Get View [page load] bind that `session value` to `ViewData` or `ViewBag` and then fetch the value in `js` like

In controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     //other codes
     ViewBag.UserName = Convert.ToString(Session["userName"]);
     return View();
}
```

In **JS**

```
steps: [
  {
    element: "#my-element",
    title: "Welcome to the tour" +'@ViewBag.UserName',
    content: "Content of my step"
  },
```

**Update:**

Add a hidden field in view as below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnUname" value="@ViewBag.UserName" />
```

Assign it to variable like

```
var uname=$("#hdnUname").val() //or $("#hdnUname").attr('value');
steps: [
  {
    element: "#my-element",
    title: "Welcome to the tour" +uname,
    content: "Content of my step"
  },
```

Comment: hi,Its displays "Welcome to the tour" +'@ViewBag.UserName' instead of displaying the value of UserName.i just want to display " Welcome to the tour xyz" if UserName="xyz".

Comment: @user3479588. Updated the answer!! Check and let me know!!

Comment: Anytime..  Happy coding..  :)